# Angularjs GET http request to REST server returns 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: angularjs, rest, http, jax-rs

I have a [RESTful Web Service](https://github.com/daniegarcia254/WebEng2014/tree/developer/553939_Lab2_REST/todo-rest-server) that acts as a repository of ToDo tasks.

On the other hand I have a [Web Application](https://github.com/daniegarcia254/WebEng2014/tree/developer/553939_Lab2_REST/todo-web-cli) that uses that REST Server for managing the Todo repository.

I've tried my first call from the client to the server in order to retrieve some data, but it fails.

The code in the REST Server is as follows:

```
/**
 * A service that manipulates ToDo's in an repository.
 *
 */
@Path("/todolist")
public class ToDoWebService {

    /**
     * The (shared) repository object. 
     */
    @Inject
    ToDoList toDoList;

    /**
     * A GET /todos request should return the ToDo's repository in JSON.
     * @return a JSON representation of the ToDo's repository.
     */
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public ToDoList getToDoList() {
        return toDoList;
    }

....
```

And the client call (in *AngularJS*):

```
(function() {
      var app = angular.module('toDoApp', []);

      var API_URI = "http://localhost:8080/todolist";

      ....
      ....

      app.controller('addToDoCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
        $scope.getToDoList = function() {
            $http.get(API_URI).
                success(function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }).
                error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log(status);
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log(headers);
                    console.log(config);
                });
        };
      }]);
....
....
})();
```

But the server always return a ***500 (Internal Server Error)***

This call it's made when you click on the "AddToDo" tab of the web application, and you can see the result of the call in the console, the error in this case.

**But the most remarkable thing is that when I change the REST Server code:**

```
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getToDoList() {
        return "It's me, example text";
    }
```

Then, it returns correctly the string "It's me, example text".

I've checked the libaries included in the 
I've checked the libaries included in the [build.gradle](https://github.com/daniegarcia254/WebEng2014/blob/developer/553939_Lab2_REST/todo-rest-server/build.gradle) file and all the [server classes](https://github.com/daniegarcia254/WebEng2014/tree/developer/553939_Lab2_REST/todo-rest-server/src/main/java/rest/todows) over and over again, finding no solution at all.

This are the headers of the HTTP request-response, all seems in order, except for the error of course:

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8080
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/todolist
Request Method:GET
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
**Request Headers**
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:es-ES,es;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost
Referer:http://localhost/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36
Response Headersview source
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:origin, content-type, accept, authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Max-Age:1209600
Connection:close
Content-Length:0
Date:Fri, 31 Oct 2014 23:45:08 GMT
```

**¿Anybody who maybe know where this error could come from?**

Comment: How is `ToDoList` type defined?

Comment: Okay, you got an error 500, so, show the server log please.

Comment: Maybe Dependency Injection with `@Inject` is not supported by the server. Maybe look into that?

Comment: Heres is the [ToDoList](https://github.com/daniegarcia254/WebEng2014/blob/developer/553939_Lab2_REST/todo-rest-server/src/main/java/rest/todows/ToDoList.java) class @PM77-1

Comment: I wish I could @denisazevedo but no exception is thrown by the server side

Comment: You can find the problem by adding a breakpoint in a `ToDoWebService` method, use `curl` or other tool for something serviced by such method, and then debug step by step until an exception is thrown (as I did!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in your POJO. You must provide a zero argument constructor to the `ToDo` class. The MOXy marshaller from POJO to JSON requires a zero argument constructor.

```
public class ToDo {

  private String task;      //Task description
  private String context;   //Task context
  private String project;   //Task project
  private int priority; //Task priority
  private URI href;
  private int id;

  // JUST ADD THIS!!!!
  public ToDo(){
  }

  //CONSTRUCTOR
  public ToDo(String task,String ctx,String proj,int pri){
    this.task = task;
    this.context = ctx;
    this.project = proj;
    this.priority = pri;
  }

  {... your code continue here ...}
}
```

Comment: @J. Lopez-pellicer. Could you see this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47336295/status-500-internal-server-error-in-ie-11-with-angular-js-application?noredirect=1#comment81625538_47336295